# Defining event handlers after readline initiated

Tags: node.js, events, fs

The textbook way to read a file line-by-line in NodeJS seems to be to call `readline.createInterface`, and then afterward attach event handlers for `line` and `close`.

There doesn't seem to be anything to "start" the reader. It just goes, and seems to work perfectly. How does it know when to start reading? How does it guarantee that those events, which don't exist yet, will always pick up every line in the file?

I always assumed that it just all happened so fast that the events get attached faster than it takes to open the file from disk and start reading it - but that doesn't really hold up.

For example, suppose I put some heavy CPU-consuming code after the lineReader has been created, but before the events attached. It still seems to work, and the event still fires for each line. How did it "wait" until the heavy stuff was done before it started reading? If I don't attach the `line` event, then it runs anyway and the `close` event still fires, so it's not like it's waiting for the `line` event to be created.

```
var lineReader = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream("input.txt")
});

// EVENTS HAVE NOT BEEN CREATED YET

lineReader.on("line", line => { console.log(line); });
lineReader.on("close", () => { console.log("DONE"); });
```

This isn't specific to `lineReader` - seems to be a common Node pattern - this is just the easiest to define and run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally, `readline.createInterface()` is creating a stream.  Streams, by default, are paused.  They unpause themselves in a number of ways and what's relevant here is when a `data` event listener is added.

And, inside of `readline.createInterface()`, a `data` event handler is added.  That starts the stream flowing and it will start emitting `data` events which the readline code will parse into line events.

Also because node.js and streams are event driven and node.js runs your Javascript as single threaded, that means that no events will occur until your setup code finishes executing.  Internally, node.js may have already started reading the file (using asynchronous I/O and threads internally), but even if it finishes the first read from the file before your setup code finishes executing, all it will do is insert a `data` event in the event queue.  node.js won't process that `data` event until your setup code is done executing and has returned control back to the node.js event loop.

Then, the `data` event callback will be called, the readline code will parse the data from that first event and if there is a full line in that first data event, it will then trigger a `line` event.

> There doesn't seem to be anything to "start" the reader.

Attaching a `data` event handler on the readStream (internal to the readline code) is what tells the stream to start flowing.

> It just goes, and seems to work perfectly. How does it know when to start reading?

Same as above.

> How does it guarantee that those events, which don't exist yet, will always pick up every line in the file?

The readline code receives raw data from the file in its `data` event handler.  It then parses that code into lines and emits `line` events for each line that it finds.  When a file read crosses a line boundary, it must buffer a partial line and wait for the rest of the line to come on the next `data` event from the stream.

When the linereader code sees that the stream is done reading and there are no more bytes, it sends the last line (if there is one in the buffer) and then issues the `close` event to tell the listener that its all done.

> For example, suppose I put some heavy CPU-consuming code after the lineReader has been created, but before the events attached. It still seems to work, and the event still fires for each line. How did it "wait" until the heavy stuff was done before it started reading?

This is because node.js is event-driven.  The first `data` event from the stream (internal to the readline code) is the result of an `fs.readFile()` function and that notifies completion through the event queue.  An event in the event queue will not be processed until the current piece of Javascript finishes and returns control back to the event loop (at which point it will then service the next event waiting in the event queue).  So, no matter how much have CPU-consuming code you have before you attach the event handlers, the internals of readline won't be told about the first data read from the file until all that is done.

It is this single-threaded, event-driven nature that ensures that you get to install your event listeners before those events can be triggered so there's no way you can miss them.

> If I don't attach the line event, then it runs anyway and the close event still fires, so it's not like it's waiting for the line event to be created.

Correct.  The readline code attaches the `data` event handler inside the `createInterface()` call, whether you have a `line` event listener or not.  So, the stream will start flowing and the file will get read whether you have a `line` event handler or not.

---

FYI, one way you can help answers these questions yourself is to just go look at the node.js code and see how it works.  That's what I did here.  Here's [a link to the `createInterface()` function](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/readline.js#L68) where you can see what I've described here.

And, you can see [here in the stream doc](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_two_modes), where is describes the three ways that a stream starts flowing, one of which is the attaching of a `data` event listener.

Comment: Wow, that's very useful, thank you very much. That clears a lot of things up things for me.

Comment: @JoeEnos - I added a few more references to the next of my answer which can help you understand in further detail.

Comment: Thanks for that link - I never looked at the node source before - that's surprisingly very readable. I really appreciate the help.